# Капуста цвітна чи кольорова?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова

Натрапила на рецепти [Обсмажена кольорова капуста з яйцями](http://cookery.com.ua/ovochi/stravi-z-kapusti/2030-obsmazhena-kolorova-kapusta-z-yajcyami.html#.XFlaz1wzbIU) та [Цвітна капуста у вершковому соусі](https://smachno.ua/ua/recepty/osnovnye-blyuda/maindishes-12920/)

Цікавить, як правильно назвати вид капусти, зображений на фото - цвітна чи кольорова? 
[image]

Вікіпедії стаття [Капуста цвітна](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%86%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0)

> Кучерява капуста, квітна капуста або цвітна капуста (Brassica oleracea
>   var. botrytis)

В Google пошук видає обидва варіанти.

Comment: Вона цвіте, тому цвітна.

Comment: А сайт, на який ви посилаєтесь де використовується *кольорова* - це, найімовірніше, google translate. Там є _Приємного Вам апетиту!_, _сама_ в сенсі *най-*.

Comment: Наведена стаття «Обсмажена кольорова капуста з яйцями» — це не дуже вдалий переклад [російської статті «Обжаренная цветная капуста с яйцами» на tvcook.ru](//www.tvcook.ru/recipes/kapusta/obzharennaya-cvetnaya-kapusta-s-yaycami.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Як правильно в коментарі каже Yola, *капуста **цвітна***, бо цвіте. (*Кольорова* — це спроба перекласти з російської прикметник *цветная*, який може позначати і «кольорова», і «цвітна», тому у випадку капусти його часто неправильно інтерпретують.)

[«Словник української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=40520&page=1280):

> **КАПУ́СТА**, и, *ж[іночий рід]*. <…>
>
> △ **(7) Цвітна́ капу́ста** — сорт капусти, суцвіття якої складається з укорочених та потовщених квітконосних пагонів, що щільно прилягають один до одного. *Цвітній капусті належить першість за вмістом найважливіших вітамінів та мінеральних речовин не лише серед інших видів капусти, а й серед овочів взагалі* (із журн.); *Показала* [Марина]*,
>   де картопля з морквою, де баняки, пояснила, як вона готує суп з цвітної капусти* (Г. Вдовиченко).

Вікіпедія в статті [«Капуста цвітна»](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%86%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0&oldid=23313539) також наводить варіанти ***квітна** капуста* й ***кучерява** капуста*, але без джерел.